# have been to/was/stay

Tags: present-perfect

If someone asks me, "what did you during the summer break?," what's the correct answer among these?

A. I stayed in New York last June for a month.

B. I've been to New York for a month.

C. I was in New York last June for a month.

Comment: Any of those is fine, although B, since it segues into the present perfect, is not altogether responsive.  The question, however, is ungrammatical: it should be worded "What did you *do* during the summer break?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choices A and C are the best. Choice B isn't right because a prepositional phrase using "to" ("to New York") doesn't fit the "I've been ... for a month" pattern--it's got to be either "I've been **staying** in New York for a month" or "I've been **in** New York for a month." The meaning of the two examples is different, though. They imply that you're still in New York. Now, if you said "I had been staying in New York for a month," it would imply that you're no longer there.